# Can you construct a mapping space from local data? (looking for reference)

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology, reference-request

I'd to know if/where there is a reference for the following construction.

Let `C_*(maps(M, T))` denote the singular chains on the space of continuous maps from an n-manifold M to some target space T.  Our goal is to construct `C_*(maps(M, T))` out of local information.  More specifically, let B be any n-manifold homeomorphic to the n-ball, and let c: \boundary(B) -> T be some fixed map.  Define `L_*(B, c)` to be the singular chains on the space of all maps B -> T which restrict to c on the boundary of B.  We want to construct `C_*(maps(M, T))` (up to homotopy) out of `{L_*(B, c)}`, where B ranges through all n-balls and c ranges through all boundary conditions.

This can be done as follows.  Let D be the category of all decompositions of M.  An object x of D is decomposition of M into n-balls.  There is a (unique) morphism x -> y if and only if x is a refinement of y (i.e. the balls of x are subdivisions of the balls of y).  Let `D_T` be a similar category, where the objects are decompositions of M into balls with the additional structure of a map from the (n-1)-skeleton of the decomposition to T, and the morphisms (anti-refinements of decompositions) are required to respect this additional structure.

We can define a functor F from `D_T` to the category of chain complexes.  Define F(x) to be the tensor product of all `L_*(B, c)`, where B ranges over all n-balls of x and c is determined by the map of the (n-1)-skeleton of x to T.  Then (theorem) `C_*(maps(M, T))` is homotopy equivalent to the homotopy colimit of F.

I doubt the above construction is new, but I haven't come across it anywhere.  Hence the question in the first sentence above.

EDIT: It looks like the special case, where T is n-connected and we use the undecorated category D instead of `D_T`, exists in some form(s) in the literature (see Oscar Randal-Williams' answer below).  So I'm particularly interested in the case where no assumptions about the connectivity of T are made.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be Theorem 3.8.6 in Lurie's DAG-VI, which he says is also in Paolo Salvatore, "Configuration spaces with summable labels", Cohomological Methods in Homotopy Theory. Progress in Mathematics 196, 2001, 375-396. They work on the space level instead of chains.

It is worth noting that Lurie has a condition for the theorem to hold: that T is dim(M)-connected, and he says that it does not hold without this assumption.

Comment: Thanks -- I had not seen Lurie's Thm 3.8.6.  But I think the statement above is more general than Thm 3.8.6.  If I understand correctly, Lurie is using iterated loop spaces, while the `{L_*(B, c)}` of my question can be thought of as iterated path spaces (if we work with spaces rather than singular chains).  I think 3.8.6 corresponds to always making the map c above the trivial map.

Anyway, helpful answer, so thanks.